# Path Range Query not working as expected in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am having two scenarios where path range query is behaving differently-

```
1. cts:search(fn:doc(), 
       cts:path-range-query("/test/path/node/Id","=","ABC_123"))
```

The above query giving me correct results

```
2. cts:search(fn:doc(), 
           cts:path-range-query("/test/path/node/Id","=","ABC 123"))
```

The Second query is not fetching any results. The document are present in Database for both `ABC_123` and `ABC 123`

I have created the path range index on `/test/path/node/Id`.

Any Suggestions ??

Comment: Could you share a (test) document that shows this behavior? Could you also share what version of MarkLogic you are using?

Comment: I am using MarkLogic 9.0.6 and seems the issue with the namespaces. I have not defined the namespace on my admin page during path range index creation. That can be the reason ?

Comment: Yes, namespaces can definitely be a problem. Define a path namespace with a prefix in admin ui, and use that in your path expression. The path query expression must match too..

Answer (score 2):

@Shalini,

I tested both queries on the console, working fine with little changes in the path:

```
 I mentioned in path range index is : test/path/node/id instead of /test/path/node/Id
```

Files tested on the console:

```
 a.xml:

  <test>
  <path>
  <node><id>ABC 123</id></node>
  </path>
  </test>
```

b.xml

```
<test>
<path>
<node><id>ABC_123</id></node>
</path>
</test>
```

The result is coming by both queries.

Comment: This should also work with a uppercase `Id`. It does for me at least.